# jQuery mobile pageinit won't happen after transition

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Page 1:

```
<a class="ui-btn-right" data-role="actionsheet">Menu</a>
<div>
   <a data-role="button" href="page2.html" data-transition="slide">Page2</a> 
   <a data-role="button" href="page3.html" data-transition="slide">Page3</a> 
</div>
```

I need to execute some script when I open `Page2`.

Page 2:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function () {
  // code
});
```

The page slides,  but the script in`Page2` won't execute.

Comment: use `.on('pageshow'` instead of `.bind('pageinit'`

Comment: @Omar, tried that, but still same result.

Comment: You should specify which page you target `$('#page2').on('pageshow', function ()` or `$(document).on('pageshow', '#page2', function ()`. Where `#page2` is the `id` of the page.